# Adding new Module is not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am trying to add a new Module to my application.
My HTML for index page is

```
<body ng-app="com.app">
```

In my app.js

```
angular.module('mod1', ['ngResource']);
angular.module('mod2', []); //this is module i want to add
var app = angular.module('com.app', ['ngResource','mod1','mod2']);
```

My Controllers1.js

```
var Controllers = angular.module('mod1');
Controllers.controller('ctrl1', function($scope,$http) {});

Controllers.controller('ctrl2', function($scope,$http) {}); //function for module 2
```

when i try to add this ctrl2 to my "controllers1.js" it works , but if i add this in my other js say "controllers2.js", its not working .
My controllers2.js is

```
'use strict';

var mymodule = angular.module('mod2');

mymodule.controller('ctrl2', function() {

    console.debug("Testing...");

});
```

summary of my question is : when i try to add my ctrl2 function to new module, its not working and on firefox console i am getting error

```
Error: Argument 'ctrl2' is not a function, got undefined 
assertArg@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:1039 
assertArgFn@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:1050 
@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:4802 
update@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:14198 
Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:8307 
updateRoute/<@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:7463 
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:6846 
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:6846 
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:6883 
Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:8057 
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:7922 
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:8143 
done@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:9170 
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:9333 
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:9304
```

I am stuck here for a long, kindly help me i shall be very thankful.
Regards,

Comment: you should create a plunker so people can help you faster :)

Comment: you can start with this one :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in your file loader (script tags, requirejs, whatever) `Controllers1.js` is right next to `controllers2.js`.

PS: some operating systems / webservers (e.g. the server inside karma on windows) are case sensitive. So try to use same case for your files (either upper or lower).

Comment: Thank you so much, i was just forgetting to add the .js in index.

Comment: I ALWAYS do this.  I'm favoriting this answer so I don't do this to myself again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tKIPDQ54JDexB7LAJpDR to see if it works in the way you want.